# I need to SOQL query UserTerritory2Association based on the Account website

Tags: soql, territory-management, territory

I need to select the UserTerritory2Association ID looking for the Territory ID associated with the account, based on the Account website.

So far I tried this:

```
    SELECT Id
FROM UserTerritory2Association
Where Territory2Id IN (
SELECT Territory2Id
FROM ObjectTerritory2Association
WHERE Object.Website = 'www.gm.com') 
LIMIT 10
```

and this

```
    SELECT Id
FROM UserTerritory2Association
Where Territory2Id IN (
SELECT Territory2Id
FROM ObjectTerritory2Association
WHERE ObjectId IN (
    SELECT Id
    FROM Account
    WHERE Website = 'www.gm.com'
)
) and RoleInTerritory2 = 'Account Manager'
LIMIT 5
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

Due to the indirect relationships of the ObjectTerritory2Association and the UserTerritory2Association objects, it does not appear possible to return a list of  UserTerritory2Association records related to accounts with the same territory assignment and a specific website in a single query.

Your first query would work if you could traverse the polymorphic ObjectId lookup to filter on Website, like Object.Website, but this isn't allowed. Using TYPEOF will allow you to query related record data from a polymorphic lookup but you can't filter on the them so it won't resolve your request.

```
SELECT Territory2Id,
  TYPEOF Object
    WHEN Account THEN Website
    ELSE Name
  END
FROM ObjectTerritory2Association
```

The second query is invalid due to the fact that nesting of semi join sub-selects are not supported, thus you would need to use two queries to obtain this list of records.